# Why couldn't I get the size of a range in range-v3?

Tags: c++, c++11, clang, c++14, range-v3

I want to get the number of people whose name starts with 'T':

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <range\v3\all.hpp>

using namespace ranges;

int main()
{
    const auto names = std::vector<std::string> {"Tony", "Peter"};

    std::cout << size(names | view::filter([](const auto& s) {return s[0] == 'T';}));
}
```

But I got huge compile error:

```
λ clang -std=c++14 test.cpp
test.cpp:11:18: error: no matching function for call to object of type 'const ranges::v3::adl_size_detail::size_fn'
std::cout << size(names | view::filter([](const auto& s) {return s[0] == 'T';}));
             ^~~~
K:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\range/v3/size.hpp:90:32: note: candidate template
  ignored: substitution failure [with Rng =
  ranges::v3::remove_if_view<ranges::v3::iterator_range<std::_Vector_const_iterator<std::_Vector_val<std::_Simple_types<std::basic_string<char,
  std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > >,
  std::_Vector_const_iterator<std::_Vector_val<std::_Simple_types<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>,
  std::allocator<char> > > > > >, ranges::v3::logical_negate<(lambda at test.cpp:11:44)> >]: no matching function
  for call to 'size'
            constexpr auto operator()(Rng &&rng) const ->
                           ^
K:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\range/v3/utility/iterator.hpp:405:32: note: candidate
  function template not viable: requires 2 arguments, but 1 was provided
        iterator_size_t<I> operator()(I begin, S end) const
```

By the way, I use the clang 3.7 in the Visual Studio 2015 Update 1.
So, what's wrong?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You're better off with the `count_if` algorithm.

```
auto cnt = ranges::count_if( names, [](const auto& s) {return s[0] == 'T';} )
```

Answer (score 22):

Use `distance`, not `size`. The latter is for ranges whose size can be retrieved in constant time.

Comment: This. And I should think about improving the error message since this is going to be a common mistake.

Comment: Just stumbled on this. So yes, a better error message in this regard will be really helpful.

Comment: so if I have a vector-based range, on which I do transform, can I do `my_transformed_range.size()`?